# How to input two functions into 1 cell?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to have 2 custom functions in one cell?

I currently have one function and another function connected through a & symbol. But what ends up happening is that both of them run at the same time, thus producing two results in one cell. I want it to be so that when one is true the other one won't be seen and only the result of one will be showing.

Any help?

Comment: First of all, you've tagged the question incorrectly as your question does not anywhere state that you are trying to achieve your requirement using Google Apps Script or using Spreadsheet formulas, If you could elaborate on your question then it would help us help you in a better way.

Comment: You should include at least some attempt at conveying how your functions are laid out, and how you call the functions.

Answer (score 0):

Just use IF

```
=IF(fn1(B1), fn1(B1), "") & IF(fn2(B1), fn2(B1), "")
```

if fn1() returns false the first part will be an empty string "" otherwise it will be the result. Same for the second part.

[IF documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)